# Add to ArrayList

Tags: java, android

This is a part of my code:

```
int n= random.nextInt(images.length - 1);        
iv.setImageResource(images[n]);
```

`Int n` choose one of the indexes randomly and then I used `ImageResource` to show pictures according to the the random indexes. Now I want to add `n` to `ArrayList`. How should I do it? Is there any better way to save a value in memory in android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare a ArrayList like the one below,

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

And once you set the Image add that to your ArrayList like this,

```
int n = random.nextInt(images.length - 1);        
iv.setImageResource(images[n]);  
list.add(n);
```

Comment: `i` for an arraylist is maybe not the best variable choice.

Comment: @assylias you are absolutely right.. well, you know competition in who first posts the valuable answer is much more important right. So to cut the time, I just used a one letter variable.